# Princípios fundamentais REST

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, owin

Neste [Artigo do Infoq](http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/rest-introduction), o autor destaca os cinco princípios fundamentais do REST:

1. Dê a todas as coisas um Identificador
2. Vincule as coisas (recursos/identificador)
3. **Utilize métodos padronizados**
4. Recursos com múltiplas representações
5. Comunique sem estado

Porém, um deles gostaria que me ajudassem a entender melhor, trata-se do princípio **Utilize métodos padronizados**. Em resumo o autor diz que:

> Em uma abordagem HTTP RESTful, você teria que começar por uma inteface
>   genérica que compusesse o protocolo HTTP do aplicativo. Você poderia
>   fazer algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha dúvida:**

- Como ficaria esta `interface` (com base na imagem)?
- Como ficaria a implementação de um `recurso (ID - Identificador)` caso queira passar um objeto `json` por exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como ficaria esta interface (com base na imagem)?

Depende do seu sistema, mas normalmente um sistema que implementa a REST API (Web API 2 é um dos *frameworks* que implementa o padrão) tem como interface o suporte a esses quatro métodos (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` e `DELETE`). [Aqui tem uma lista com todos os métodos suportados pelo protocolo HTTP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm). A maioria deles não são imprescindíveis. Você implementa se quiser.

A interface normalmente é definida pela rota padrão + método. No seu exemplo, você sabe que se chamar `/orders` por `GET`, você obterá a lista completa de entidades do tipo `order` do serviço, e se passar um objeto serializado por `PUT` (como um JSON, que é o mais comum, até um XML), você está inserindo uma nova entidade do tipo `order` no armazenamento desse serviço.

No caso do Web API 2, a documentação sobre as interfaces é gerada automaticamente pelo *framework*. Tal recurso é conhecido como [`ApiExplorer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apiexplorer(v=vs.118).aspx).

> Como ficaria o recurso (ID) caso queira passar um objeto json, por exemplo?

Depende de cada serviço. Se implemento um serviço aceitando que o `id` será definido por uma requisição `PUT` ou ainda `POST` (o que não é recomendado, mas é possível). A maioria dos serviços definem sozinho o id do novo registro. Quando isso acontece, os dados do novo registro são devolvidos no cabeçalho da resposta da requisição. [Você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) (seção "Creating a Resource").